# ffprobe bitrate missing for LIVE streams

Tags: ffprobe

The bitrate is shown when querying static video files but it is not when analysing live HTTP or RTMP streams.
Increasing -probesize and -analyzeduration does't affect the result. Bitrate is always N/A. How can I get bitrate info without saving a chunck of stream on disk first?